# Does Dueling in Brotherhood of Blood affect K/D spread?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Does the dueling arena in the `Brotherhood of Blood` covenant affect you K/D spread?

i.e. The amount of glowing rank when you are a red phantom.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will lose one rankpoint per duel lost.

I.e if you are have one victory total (rankpoint 1) and then lose, you will be reverted to rankpoint 0. However you cannot fall below 0.

However, if you have achieved 50 kills/victories and achieved Rank 1 (which rewards you with a weapon and an aura effect) then lose a battle (49 rankpoints) the aura effect will be removed.

The [wiki](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Brotherhood+of+Blood) describes all the requirements for ranking up in the Brotherhood of Blood

Comment: Rank or rank point?

Comment: Yeah that was tricky. Each rank gives a reward (which will never be revoked, except the aura) whereas a rank point contributes toward each rank. Edited the question to accommodate for this clarification.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. Now losing doesn't sound so bad. :-D